# Why $('a.current').removeClass('current'); is not working?

Tags: javascript, parent-child, jquery, jquery-tools

Why `$('a.current').removeClass('current');` is not working for this jquery tabs?
http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/ytnw9/8/

```
 //full JS in http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/ytnw9/8/
 $(function(){
 var list=$('#list'),
     elementsPerRow=-1,
     loop=true,
     // find first image y-offset to find the number of images per row
     topOffset=list.find('a:eq(0)').offset().top,
     numTabs=list.find('li').length-1,
     current,newCurrent;

 function changeTab(diff){
  // a.current set by jQuery Tools tab plugin
  $('li.current').removeClass('current');
  current=list.find('a.current').parent('li').addClass('current').index();
  newCurrent=(loop)?(current+diff+numTabs+1)%(numTabs+1):current+diff;
 if(loop){
   if(newCurrent>numTabs){newCurrent=0;}
   if(newCurrent<0){newCurrent=numTabs;}
 }else{
   if(newCurrent>numTabs){newCurrent=numTabs;}
   if(newCurrent<0){newCurrent=0;}
 }
  // don't trigger change if tab hasn't changed (for non-looping mode)
 if (current!=newCurrent){
   list.find('li').eq(current).removeClass('current');
   list.find('li').eq(newCurrent).addClass('current').find('a').trigger('click'); // trigger click on tab
 }
 }
 list
  // set up tabs
  .tabs("#content",{effect:'ajax',history:true, xonBeforeClick:function(){changeTab(0)}})
  // find number of images on first row
  .find('a').each(function(i){
      if(elementsPerRow<0&&$(this).offset().top>topOffset){
         elementsPerRow=i;
      }
  });
 //$('a').filter('.current').parent('li').addClass('current'); // Why does not work?
 //$('a.current').parent('li').addClass('current'); // Why does not work?

 $('ul#list li').click(function(){$('li.current').removeClass('current');$(this).addClass('current')});
 $('a.current').removeClass('current'); // Why does not work?
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="one.html" title="one">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="two.html" title="two">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="three.html" title="three">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>​
```

Comment: Whilst it's nice to see source code posted, please can you format it to make it more readable. Great big walls of code don't attract people willing to spend time decyphering it so they can start helping you. Also try to reduce the amount of code to as little as possible and the problem can be still be reproduced. And importantly, describe what the code is supposed to do. I think this have something to do with tabs but you need to tell us more precisely what is does and what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (I don't yet have a working page running your code), but it appears that the "current" class is only applied to "li" elements.

I think your $("a.current") will always contain 0 elements.

Comment: Then why Firebug and Chrome Inspect element shows that `a` has class `current`?

Answer (score 1):

Your [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) call is working *does* clear the class, but then this line in your history plugin:

```
links.eq(0).trigger("history", [h]);
```

Is triggering your it to load the first link as in the `<iframe>` as the default...which is selecting that link again, adding the class back, it's ultimately the tab plugin selecting the first tab and at this line:

```
tab.addClass(conf.current);
```

Adding the class back to the anchor (the anchor is `tab` at that point).

[Here's your fiddle updated with an alert to see what's happening a bit easier](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ytnw9/9/).

Comment: Change to `tab.parent('li').addClass(conf.current);` fixes `li.current` that I need, **but it stops key event working**. Some idea to fix it? Is there some other way to enable `$('a.current').removeClass('current');` working?

Comment: @Binyamin - It's a timing issue, you need to trigger it after the first history call, which is triggering your tabs...or disable history defaults, by taking out the else statement with that link above altogether.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work because you haven't any `<a>` in your page with the class .current

You can check it out by yourself :

`alert($('a.current').length);`

will return you 0...

Comment: Then why Firebug and Chrome Inspect element shows that `a` has class `current`?